# Android: Layout appears truncated on real phone

Tags: android, android-layout

All along I've been testing on an Android 2 version ported to x86 (which runs within VirtualBox), due to problems with the emulators. My application and layout appears fine on this port.

I am now finishing my development, and am testing on my real phone, a Droid Bionic.

However, my overall application layout does not take up the full size of my screen, even when I have my dimensions set to the below. There is a black outer box that it seems to reside within and I can't enlarge this window.
If I change the dimensions of my overall layout from fill_parent to say 1000px, I can see the layout being truncated as it still sits within this unchanged window size.

Can anyone advise me how to resolve this?

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/overall_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0px"
    android:background="@layout/grid_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I am fairly sure this is because of the screen compatibility mode you are running in because your android:targetSdkVersion in your manifest is set incorrectly. This should be set to the highest SDK version that you have tested your app with and it works on.'

[Please see this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) and in specific read the first few paragraphs.

> There are two versions of screen compatibility mode with slightly
> different behaviors: Version 1 (Android 1.6 - 3.1)
>
> The system draws the application's UI in a "postage stamp" window.
> That is, the system draws the application's layout the same as it
> would on a normal size handset (emulating a 320dp x 480dp screen),
> with a black border that fills the remaining area of the screen.
>
> To disable this version of screen compatibility mode, you simply need
> to set android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion to "4" or
> higher, or set android:resizeable to "true".

Edit: [Please see the documentation on how you should be setting the target SDK attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

These lines in particular are of interest:

> To maintain your application along with each Android release, you
> should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API
> level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding
> platform version.

Given that your ran into this issue tells me your target sdk is set to 3 or lower. So Android 1.5 or lower. This means that anyone running your app on a phone with something newer then Android 1.5 is going to be running in compatibility mode. This leads to decreased performance and incompatible default graphics. I.E. the graphics will not look like what everything else on the phone looks like because of the compatibility mode.

Currently something like 95% of all Android are running a newer version then 1.5.
What you need to do is up your tarket SDK to 4,5,6,7 ... etc one at a time and fully test the App until you get to the current SDK release of 15. When you release the target SDK should be 15 to ensure it runs well on all OS versions.

Comment: No, this padding is not the issue (as I tested the removal of it). This only affects the positioning of the GridView within the LinearLayout. My issue is like as if there is padding between the main phone screen and my LinearLayout

Comment: That is odd. In your Manifest file what is the android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion set to. Maybe you are running in some sort of compatibility mode on the phone.

Comment: You have not answered me, but I am fairly sure this is being caused by an incorrectly set android:targetSdkVersion. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Excellent! I set the resizable to true and now I get a full screen, thanks

Comment: I still recommend that instead of that you should up the target SDK 1 at a time, test on that SDK fully and then repeat. Until you get to the current release SDK. This is what google recommends doing. Otherwise you could have other weird issues like this that vary depending on what OS the phone running the App is running. I am updating the answer to give more info on this.

Comment: When you say test on the different SDK's, do you mean test using the emulator or a phone for each one?

Comment: Ideally all testing should be done on a real phone. But that is probably not possible, so test using the emulator for each SDK, or use a real phone if you have one for that OS version.

Comment: Have had big problems getting emulators working locally, so may just buy some second hand phones to test out a selection

Comment: That is the safest way. I own a phone that is OS 2.1, one that is 2.2, one on 3.1, and one on 4.0 so combined I tested 95+% of the popular OS versions. The emulators have worked decent for me, If you just stick with Google recommendation of using Eclipse + their SDK on windows I have not had any issues. Although they are still emulators, so you cannot really trust anything on them.